# Chrome Extension JS .click(); not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

So guys let me explain this problem all the code works fine but the .click is not working am trying to make it click on the website button but for some reason its not clicking on it is this a bug or something?

Thank you very much.

CODE:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

    document.getElementById('status').textContent = "Going To Localhost";
    chrome.tabs.query( { active: true, currentWindow: true }, function( tabs ) {
        chrome.tabs.update( tabs[0].id, { url: "http://localhost/" } );
    });
    var button = document.getElementById("mybutton");
    button.addEventListener("click", function() {
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {code: 'document.getElementById("username").value = "user";'}, function(){
            chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {code: 'document.getElementById("password").value = "pass";'}, function(){
                chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {code: 'var this_button = document.getElementsByClassName("btnLogin"); this_button.click();'}, function(){
                });
            });
        });
    }, false);

},function(errorMessage) {
    alert(errorMessage);
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getElementsByClassName` (note the pluralization) returns a [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/NodeList). So you'd need to access the first element like:

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {code: 'var this_button = document.getElementsByClassName("btnLogin"); this_button[0].click();'});
```

**OR**, modern browser that Chrome is, you can use [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) instead:

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {code: 'var this_button = document.querySelector(".btnLogin"); this_button[0].click();'});
```

Comment: P.S. You should check your console for errors, it would have told you that there was no method `click`

Comment: I'll look in to the console for errors from now on.

Comment: @BSXIOS No problem, don't forget to check out the updated answer.

Comment: May i ask why this isnt working i want it to wait until the next page loads                  `chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {code: 'var this_button = document.getElementsByClassName("btnLogin"); this_button[0].click();document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {alert("SSSSS");});'}, function () {
                });`

Comment: You can't put DOMContentLoaded inside your `executeScript` because it's likely already been fired, although your original script should be triggered on the next page

Comment: Hm then how do i wait for the next page to load before execution?